# How to add granite package

Tags: development, vala

What package do I need to add to my project in order to use granite? All I get is "The name `Granite' does not exist in the context of..."

I tried libgranite-dev but it isn't found.

Also, why is this information not clearly laid out somewhere? I've been struggling with the same thing on the math library as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so turns out it is just granite and that package names are listed in parenthesis on valadoc.org when you search for Granite(granite). I do wish it was more clear on the github page how to do this though. I only found it by looking at another project that was using it.